# Trouble with existing database interference while setting up Sail? Lost connection, system error: 0

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

In the process of trying to move over a project to a docker container via Sail.
There was an issue where the mysql container didn't want to run due to there already being something on the same port (the database for the current working version).

So I tried changing the port to 3366 instead in the env file and that seems to have gotten the container to run now, but while trying to connect to it with mysql workbench I either get:

> Lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

while connecting to 3366, or

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password: YES)

when connecting to 3306, the original port.
Also when inspecting what the mysql container spits out in docker there's a line:

> [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.27'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

My first thought is that 3366 isn't in effect somehow, despite being able to see changes to other variables via the env. Anything that might help figure this out?

Comment: Other containers within the sail stack connect through the `sail` network, so they will connect using the *container* port. Workbench is not on the same docker network, so it will be communicating through the port mapping you've made in the compose file.

Comment: If that isn't enough to help you solve the problem, you should edit your question with the docker compose file, and any relevant `env` values (remember not to post sensitive data)

Comment: I did get that far already to check the docker-compose.yml file. The only line I can think of as relevant is:
ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3366}:3366'

Comment: Unless you're using a customized mysql image, it listens on port 3306. You should be forwarding 3366 to that. `'${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3366}:3306'`. The conflict is on the HOST, not the container.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, thanks!